# You must declare scalar variable @xml_var

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 Express and I'm testing this code on a Query window:

```
DECLARE @xml_var XML
SET @xml_var = 
(
    SELECT ID_CODE AS '@ProductionId',
        CODE AS '@ItemId',
        CODE_LEVEL AS '@ItemPackagingLevelId',
        COMMISIONING_FLAG AS '@ItemFlag',
        TIMESPAN AS '@TimeStamp',
        USERNAME AS '@Username',
        SOURCE AS '@Source'
        FROM TRZIC.dbo.CODES_TEMP
    FOR XML PATH('Item'),
    ROOT('Commissioning')
)
GO

-- Call remote procedure passing it the xml
EXEC [UIC160\SQLEXPRESS].TRZIC.dbo.AddCommissioning @xml_var;
GO
```

But here, `EXEC [UIC160\SQLEXPRESS].TRZIC.dbo.AddCommissioning @xml_var;`, I get this error:

`You must declare scalar variable @xml_var.`

This is my first time I do this and I don't know how to solve this problem.

**How can I solve it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the first `go`:

```
DECLARE @xml_var XML
SET @xml_var = 
(
    SELECT ID_CODE AS '@ProductionId',
        CODE AS '@ItemId',
        CODE_LEVEL AS '@ItemPackagingLevelId',
        COMMISIONING_FLAG AS '@ItemFlag',
        TIMESPAN AS '@TimeStamp',
        USERNAME AS '@Username',
        SOURCE AS '@Source'
        FROM TRZIC.dbo.CODES_TEMP
    FOR XML PATH('Item'),
    ROOT('Commissioning')
)
GO  <--- THIS ONE HERE


-- Call remote procedure passing it the xml
EXEC [UIC160\SQLEXPRESS].TRZIC.dbo.AddCommissioning @xml_var;
GO
```

The `go` statement creates separate batches and variables are defined within a batch.  And, this is actually well described in the documentation ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)).

Remove that line and it should work.  I also suggest that you put semicolons at the end of your statements.  It helps make the code clearer, seeing where statements begin and end (and SQL Server may one day require them).

Answer (score 1):

The variable scope ends after the GO statement. You should write GO after EXEC remote proc call.